# How to update table field in SQL by adding to it number received from the HTML form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

How to update table field in SQL by adding to it number received from the HTML form?

Let’s say I have a form:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="number" value="1">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have a table in MySQL:
TABLE: “test” (ID:1 | Number: 12)

Is it possible to compose sql query which lets me to add number "1" from HTML form to number 12 (ID:1) in my table?

The one way how I understand is possible to do that is to select first number from table “test” and add to it 1, then update the table with the sum what I get. But is it possible to sum 1 and 12 in more easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `UPDATE` it.

```
UPDATE test SET number = number + 1 WHERE id = 1
```

If the number being added depends on the form input, then get that value and put it in the query (don't forget to use prepared statements):

```
UPDATE test SET number = number + :newNumber WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: oh is that simple. Thank you!

Comment: You're most welcome. Mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.